Fastest Algorithm for modular exponentiation for special cases (power of 2's as the power)
Given a base $b$ and numbers $M$ and $n$ such that we need to calculate the modular residue $R$:
$b^n\ mod\ M = R$.
Now, we know that the algorithm depends on the number of bits in $n$ and $M$ given by: $\mathcal{O} \left ( \left (\log(m) \right )^2 \cdot \log(n) \right)$ (referenced here: Computational Complexity of Modular Exponentiation (from Rosen's Discrete Mathematics)).
My question is can we calculate it even faster, in special cases when the power $n$ itself is a power of 2? or repeatedly squaring $b$ and taking the mod of the square is the best we can do  even in this special case?
I couldn't find any references for the special cases thus the Q.

The powers of $b$ modulo $M$ will repeat with some period less than $M$ (possibly after some initial sequence of length less than $M$), so if $\log(n)$ is much larger than $M$ you could detect this period and use it to predict the residue of $b^n$ without computing any additional powers directly. But you might need $O(M)$ space for this, and this has little to do with $n$ being a power of $2$.

@DavidK thanks for the response. I understood what you said about the general case. But how do we predict the period if we don't know the factors of $M$ as we (if I am correct) need the factors. If true, I am afraid this doesn't answer my Q. My Q was if we could calculate faster than the given algorithm in cases where power is itself a power of 2. That is not clear.

Standard algorithms for fast exponentiation consist of repeatedly performing many multiplication/squaring steps.
It is possible to speed up the individual multiplication/squaring operations, if the numbers involved are very large.  (See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Computational_complexity_of_multiplication, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication.)  Also, the multiplication/squaring operations are a bit faster if the modulus is a power of two, but only by a constant factor, so this doesn't affect the asymptotic running time.
Despite that, there is no known way to reduce the number of multiplications/squarings, if the exponent is a power of two.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCS35.
For a general exponent, you can often slightly reduce the number of multiplications/squarings by using a good addition chain, but this only gives a constant factor improvement, so it doesn't affect the asymptotic running time.
